# Regular expression not working as expected for special characters

Tags: regex, wireshark, xml

I have a Wireshark capture and I'm trying to create a [display filter [Wireshark documentation]](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) that finds XML documents which contain the term `@@ V?` (at-at-space-V-questionmark). The documentation says Perl Regex are used:

> The matches operator makes it possible to search for text in string fields and byte sequences using a regular expression, using Perl regular expression syntax.

And

> Note: Wireshark needs to be built with libpcre in order to be able to use the matches operator.

I can't find out whether this condition applies, but in general I can use the `matches` operator, so I'd assume that part is fulfilled.

IMHO the filter `xml matches "@@ V\?"` should work, but it finds XML that does not fit the criterion, e.g. an XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dialog><sysdef name="TERMREC" value="@@ U1160613113912"/></dialog>
```

**What's wrong with my filter or with Wireshark?**

Using a filter without special characters (e.g. `xml matches "@@ V0"`) works as expected. Other filters with special characters (e.g. `xml matches "@@ V1\*"`) do not work as well.

Comment: your question isn't really clear, so do you have a regex pattern `@@ V\?` and it matches `@@ U1160613113912`?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Unfortunately, Wireshark does not display which part of the XML actually matches. A filter `xml matches "@@ V0"` for example works as expected, so I guess it has to do with the `?` which I escaped as `\?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have to use a double backslash, e.g. `xml matches "@@ V\\?"` and `xml matches "@@ V1\\*"`.

I knew this has to be done in code like C++ or C#, but didn't expect this in a user input field. Especially, I wonder why an invalid expression with a single backslash does not result in an error but provides false results instead.

I have opened [Wireshark Bug 12522](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12522).